# How to move to other viewControllers when user tap on a tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a navigation bar with a table view controller that display 4 images (4 cells). I have 4 viewControllers that I need to show when the user clicks on the cell ( each image show a specific VC ) ??

any ideas would be much appreciated

here is my code :

```
class MenuTable: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgtable: UITableView!

    var menuImage: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "image1")!,
        UIImage(named: "image2")!,
        UIImage(named: "image3")!,
        UIImage(named: "image4")!
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imgtable.dataSource = self
        imgtable.delegate = self
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuImage.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("menucell") as! Menucell
        cell!.imageview.image = menuImage[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: did you even tried to google it ?

Comment: give each button a tag. so they will have tags 0, 1, 2, 3. now let them all trigger the same method on click. on click check what is the tag of the button, if it is 0, open vc 0. do you know how to initiateand display a view controller?

Comment: With only four possibilities, learning about static cells should be an option: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of `UITableView` like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var viewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController1") as! viewController1
        case 1:
            viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController2") as! viewController2
        case 2:
            viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController3") as! viewController3
        case 3:
            viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController4") as! viewController4
        default:
            print("default")
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: yes my friend , still not working !! , man i have issue with the selection of the cells the function is not working because there is no selection

Comment: @Mriyadh Is your view Controllers placed on main storyboards with segue?

Comment: @Mriyadh check that your tableview's `delegate` is set with your `viewController`

Comment: it was my fault my friend the table view selection property was disabled , now its work very fine . many thanx for ur gr8 efforts

Comment: Welcome mate :) Happy Coding :)